# Android ActionItem Overflow not shown

Tags: java, android, menuitem

I've set up a small sample project (https://github.com/mikepenz/HoloKitKatDrawer)
for my applications, and uploaded it to github. 
It is a really helpful wrapper for applications with a drawerlayout and fragments
as content.

Now i got a problem. If i try to inflate my menu like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

it doesn't show all items which are to much for the actionbar. It will simply
forget or ignore them. The same happens if i set showAsAction="never"

I never had this issue before. (I also have a device without a menu button).

You can find the rest of the source code at my github. https://github.com/mikepenz/HoloKitKatDrawer

Someone got an idea what i do wrong with the project so it will handle the ActionItems
wrong?

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: You need to return `true` from onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: @Karakuri thanks for your answer. I return true via the super method. It's always a good idea to call the super method so you don't remove standard behavior which was implemented in a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. It is kind of annoying that i had this issue for weeks but never saw it, because i had no ActionOverflow in my current applications.

The issue is quite simple. I tried to set the ActionOverflow icon manually by theme, with a custom graphic.
If you set your graphic like this in your theme it will ignore the ActionOverflowIcon and simply hide it.

Here's the corresponding commit to fix the issue:
https://github.com/mikepenz/HoloKitKatDrawer/commit/6d6022282655e451e557e61e9cb3fbcc3883f6d5

I know it's possible to set the graphic via theme too, but it won't work like this:

```
<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@drawable/ic_ab_overflow_holo_dark</item>
```

You have to define a style here, and within this style you are able to set the icon too.